# How to move from one drive to another that's a different size?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, migration

I've run into this scenario a few time: I need to replace a drive because I need more space, it's having problems, moving to a new box, etc.

What's the best way to copy data from one partition size to another (presuming the target has enough space)?

What about if it's a different file system (such as ReiserFS to ext4)?

If it's just a new drive on an existing system, how do I ensure I don't need to reinstall to get everything working?

**Update** - many of the options are highly viable, and I've changed this question to community wiki because I don't think there's a "right" answer.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/32164/easiest-way-to-clone-boot-partition-onto-new-hard-drive was asked for windows drives/partitions

Answer (score 10):

Clone the drive using [CloneZilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/), then use [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to resize it.  Keep your old one in case if goes wrong :-)

By the way, this way is free.

Comment: I like the free part here, though nothing beats GOOD working software that does everything (instead of 3 freewares together)

Comment: It's just two freewares and it's quite painless.  ISOs boot no problem.

Comment: I can confirm that this works. I successfully moved my secondary drive with Windows 7 from a 160GB drive to a 1TB drive. Cloned it to my linux disk with Clonezilla. Restored it on the new disk and resized it with the Windows 7 Disk Management tool. This was from a NTFS to a NTFS though.

Comment: you say 'clone the drive' though he asked clone the partition. Also he said different file system.

Answer (score 5):

The solution I've used in the past is `tar`. If the partitions are the exact same size and type, you can use `dd`.

Here's my answer to the quandary:

1. boot using a live cd distro such as [Slax](http://slax.org)
2. verify the partitions you want are on the new drive
3. make sure both the old and new drives are mounted, for example `/tmp/driveold` and `/tmp/drivenew`
4. run from a terminal the following `tar` command:

   `(tar cp --xattrs /tmp/driveold/path) | (tar x /tmp/drivenew/path)`
5. repeat for each partition you need to copy

This works for every partition I've ever tried it on (excluding `/boot`, for which I ensure the partitions are identical, and use `dd`).

Comment: I like this solution because it's so simple, but I think you would need some extra options like p (preserve permissions) to get all of the meta-data.

Comment: you're right on the p - I've added that :)

Comment: Speaking of meta-data, the `--xattrs` option (store ACLs and SELinux info) should be used too.

Comment: The 2 tars connected with a pipe could be replaced with `cpio --pass-through`.

Comment: What version of `tar` has an `--xattrs` option?  Not mine.  I suggest using `rsync` or plain `cp` instead: http://serverfault.com/questions/306538/how-to-move-linux-to-another-partition/306699#306699

Comment: Beware that when combining `dd` and `tar` as proposed in the answer, the root filesystem will likely change its UUID which can make the boot fail under some circumstances. I usually prefer to copy (through `tar`), `chroot` to the copy target (`mount -o bind` the `/dev` directory first!) and then issue `grub-install` or even `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` or whatever the Linux distribution prefers the GRUB reinstallation procedure to be called. When using `cpio` be aware of its size limits (`tar` can really be recommended here?)

Answer (score 2):

This is one reason I like LVM.  Just add the new disk to the volume group, `pvmove` the logical volumes from the old to new disk, remove the old disk from the volume group, and then from the system.  If it's your boot disk you're replacing then you also need to update your boot loader.

Comment: That *is* a great idea - except if you're not running LVM, it's a bit of a pain :)
Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: Something to consider next time you install :-)

Answer (score 2):

+1 to warren and to use tar.

However, I usually tries to restore from my backups instead. 
And moving from one disk to a new one seems like a good opportunity to see if your backup plan is working.

If you simulate a disk failure (pull the power from the old disk), 
start to recover to the new disk.
And when you are done, you start up the old disk and diff them to see if you got all the files.

If they are identical you both have moved all your data, and you know that your backup plan is valid and working.

Comment: good idea - though for those among us (<whistle mode="innocent"/>) who don't have a "backup" solution, this might also be a Good Time to come up with one :)

Comment: :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to boot from a liveCD and mount the old drive as read only. This is to prevent the livecd from changing it during the copy. Then `rsync -avz /mnt/olddisk/ /mnt/newdisk` (the trailing slash after olddisk is necessary). As the others have mentioned, if this is the boot disk that is being expanded you will need to rerun `grub-install <new device>` before it can be bootable.

Comment: there's one I'd not thoguht of :)

Answer (score 1):

Create image from original partition and put this image to new HDD.

[Norton Ghost™ 14.0](http://www.symantec.com/norton/ghost) do that or other image software

---

Here is list of disk cloning software

[Comparison of disk cloning software [wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_cloning_software)

Comment: Acronis True Image is another alternative (http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/)

Comment: Unfortuately this method requires purchasing Norton Ghost

Answer (score 1):

Most [disk cloning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_cloning_software) utilities can do this.  I like using g4u from a livecd.  Ghost is nice, but I'd rather use a free one.