# Clone Hard Disk Software

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What utility can move my Windows boot partition over to another hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/32164/what-utility-can-move-my-windows-boot-partition-over-to-another-hard-drive)

Can someone recommend some software (free or opensource) that will allow me to make a clone of a working hard disk that was taken from an identical system.  This is for Windows Vista.

I am unable to install Vista from scratch, something to do with Vista and SATA and the BIOS is very basic.  Thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/11453/how-to-move-from-one-drive-to-another-thats-a-different-size

Comment: @harrymc, vote to close if you think so.  There are enough 3k'ers that we shouldn't need the mods.

Comment: In Super User, and all the StackExchange sites, shopping or product recommendations are considered off topic and open ended, and sometimes even too localized. Try to reword your question in a way that you are not asking for products, but more of processes; this will help keep it on topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[EASEUS Disk Copy](http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/)** is a potent freeware providing sector-by-sector disk/partition clone regardless of your operating system, file systems and partition scheme by creating a bootable CD. The sector-by-sector method assures you a copy 100% identical to the original. Disk Copy can be used for copy, cloning, or upgrading your original small hard drive to a new larger drive. Simply speaking, it can copy anything from the old hard drive including the deleted, lost files and inaccessible data.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend you [HDClone](http://www.miray.de/products/sat.hdclone.html#free) or [DriveImage](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm). Both are free.

Answer (score 4):

Might have a look at [clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/).

Answer (score 1):

[Partimage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page) saves the hard disk as a image, and also allows to be uploaded to any network loction

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will work with your hard drives, it is the Western Digital<sup>®</sup> version of Acronis True Image and it's free - http://support.wdc.com/product/downloaddetail.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try [Macrium](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.asp) (Free):

> - A free disaster recovery solution for your home computer
> - Protect your personal documents, photos, music and emails
> - Clone your hard disk and create disk images in the safe knowledge that everything is securely saved in an easily recovered backup file

Answer (score 1):

Unless the source machine and the destination machine has identical hardware setup, you might run into problems where it's missing an important driver, and just craps out when you put in the drive.

I know that's the case back in Windows XP with HD controller drivers. Might want to sysprep the machine before cloning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) (particularly the LiveCD version) myself.

Comment: GParted is available on the [SystemRescueCD](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/sysrescuecd/); it helped me recently when I needed to copy partitions from an infected Windows 7 system to another drive. I also use [Clonezilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonezilla).