# How can I move Ubuntu installation from one USB to another?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, storage, migration

Is it possible to move Ubuntu 9.10 installation from a 4gb USB to a 16gb USB?  I'd appreciate layman instructions since I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: [How to move from one drive to another that's a different size?](http://superuser.com/questions/11453/how-to-move-from-one-drive-to-another-thats-a-different-size)

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to clone the installation then delete the original later.

I used these (archived) instructions:
[How to clone your bootable Ubuntu install to another drive](http://web.archive.org/web/20090430222715/http://www.arsgeek.com/2008/01/22/how-to-clone-your-bootable-ubuntu-install-to-another-drive/)

> If you’ve ever wanted to completely clone your Ubuntu install, with all of the tweaks, files you’ve downloaded and changes you’ve made to it, there’s a fairly simple way to do this. This is great if you want a complete backup, or if you’re looking to move your system to a newer (read: bigger, faster, stronger) hard drive or even just to clone your install to other machines with the same hardware...