# Copy the contents of one partition to another partition hardrive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr

if i write this command in linux "dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sda2" it will copy the whole /dev/sda1 partition bit by bit to /dev/sda2 ......is there any way in **WINDOWS** not in linux that i can just only copy the contents of one partition and also the **MBR** to another partition not the whole partition....Why **MBR** bcoz i want to take a boot from the copied partition and that is only possible if there is **MBR** in the copied partition.....

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719186/copy-the-contents-of-one-hard-drive-partition-to-anohter-hard-drive-partition

Comment: What file system is on the device?

Comment: The file system on the device is ntfs......

Comment: copying an entire MBR to a VBR (volume/partition boot record) is probably a bad idea.  at the least you'll be copying the MBR partition table which isn't useful.  i'm pretty sure windows already puts its bootloader on the VBR of its system drive, which is why grub can boot it with *"chainloader +1"* ... in other words, if you copy a bootable partition with *dd* you'll already have the bootloader in the VBR and copying the MBR will just be messing things up.

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/11453/how-to-move-from-one-drive-to-another-thats-a-different-size ?

Answer (score 4):

First, /dev/sda is not a partition: it is a whole disk. Partitions are /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2 … as the disk is partitioned. So, supposing that you want to copy /dev/sda1 to /dev/sda2, you have to:

Mount the partitions (create the directories first):

```
mkdir /mnt/sda1 /mnt/sdb1
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
```

Then copy the content of the first partition to the second.

```
cp -a -x /mnt/sda1 /mnt/sdb1
```

You can then unmount the partitions and delete the mount-place directories.

```
umount /mnt/sda1
umount /mnt/sdb1
rm -r /mnt/sda1 /mnt/sdb1
```

Comment: can you plz kindly explain a little bit that what this command actually does.......

Comment: To know more about what the cp command does, `man cp`.

Comment: wiil this commnand also copy the MBR from dev/sda1 to /dev/sdb1 becoz i also need to boot from the dev/sdb1.....

Comment: No, the method described above won't copy the MBR. If you want to clone a disk/partition, maybe you could have a look at clonezilla.

Comment: thank u so much dtrosset....
                 but the way im looking for it is that how i will copy the whole contents of one partition to another partition in Window..?if you anyone have any idea about this plz let me know....

Answer (score 2):

[Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/) will do this

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to do that (not sure about the MBR though, but the doc says it « creates identical bootable partitions », so I guess so) with **DrvClonerXP** : it quiclky copies the exact content of a partition to an existing partition. I haven't made tests, but since (as I understand) it copies byte-for-byte rather than file-by-file, it must be much faster than Robocopy or similar tools, especially when there are many small files.