# Changing filesystem types "safely"

Tags: upgrade, conversion, filesystems, data-recovery, data-integrity

Back in Windows 95 OSR2 (I believe), there was a conversion tool that would take your extant FAT16 partition and change it to FAT32 non-destructively (most of the time).

Are there any tools like that now for going from one file system type to another *in situ* without destroying the data?

Examples: from etx3 to ext4? Or NTFS to XFS?

Comment: I just picked those two as examples.. any others would be cool/fun, too - ReiserFS3 to JFS or FAT to etx2...

Comment: this could be done to a new fs/partition with some of the techniques here: http://superuser.com/questions/11453/how-to-move-from-one-drive-to-another-thats-a-different-size

Comment: "Windows 95 ... would ... change it to FAT32 non-destructively (most of the time)" made me laugh. Most of the time is such a great description of Windows 95. Most of the time it didn't crash (if you rebooted once a day). Most of the time networking would work. Most of the time...

Comment: @Wayne Johnston - yes yes, we all look back and laugh at Windows 95 :) ..but whether it was funny or always successful, it was still a nifty function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ext3 to ext4 you can use:

tune2fs -O extents,uninit_bg,dir_index /dev/yourfilesystem

followed by:

fsck -pDf /dev/yourfilesystem

To return the system to a consistent state. However, I don't believe (someone correct me if I'm wrong) that this is a complete conversion. I believe there may be an issue with extents...

For FAT to NTFS:

convert (your drive letter here): /fs:ntfs

NTFS to XFS I have no idea but I would doubt it. NTFS is proprietary...

Answer (score 1):

the built in **convert** command in Windows (even in windows 7), let you convert a FAT filesystem to NTFS,

For other convertions **Partition Magic** may do the job.