# Move Ubuntu to another drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a laptop with an 80GB SSD and 500GB HDD.  I currently have Windows installed on the SSD, and a 400GB data partition for Windows on the HDD.  I set aside 100GB on the HDD to try out Ubuntu, and I'd like to make it my primary OS and switch it over to the (much) faster SSD.

How could I go about getting my Ubuntu setup moved over to the SSD?  I have a 120GB USB hard drive I can use if necessary for getting through it.

Comment: some of the ideas on this similar question may help: http://superuser.com/questions/11453/how-to-move-from-one-drive-to-another-thats-a-different-size

Answer (score 0):

In brief, boot from a rescue or live Linux system. Mount the two partitions. Assuming you don't mind blowing away the Windows partition on SSD. Format the destination (e.g. mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/ssd1). Mount them (e.g. /mnt/ssd, /mnt/hdd) copy the files:

```
umask 0
cd /mnt/hdd
for D in  boot  etc lib lib64 media  opt  sbin  tmp  var
bin  dev home  lib32 root usr ; do
   tar cf - $D | (cd /mnt/ssd ; tar xf - )
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently, and I used [partimage](http://www.partimage.org/), which is nice. It is a console app that is fast and reliable and free as in freedom, and makes an exact duplicate of your partitions without fuss. However, it only works for supported file systems, and does not currently support ext4 or btrfs. Also, it is normally used with unmounted partitions. In your case, you'd need to use a live cd per Keith above.